# Convert Hex to Binary on large file

Tags: bash, awk, binary, hex, data-conversion

I have a text file with ~2.3 million lines.  Each line contains a 64 character hexadecimal string. I am trying to read in the file line by line and convert the hex string to binary and output to a file. I wrote this simple loop below in bash, but I know it is not optimal and it will take forever to complete.

Is there a faster way, using awk for instance?  Better to use perl?  I just need something that is much faster.

```
cat /tmp/hexFile.log | while read line
do
bin=$(echo "obase=2; ibase=16; $line" | bc )
bin=`echo $bin | sed 's/\\\ //g'`
echo $bin >> /tmp/binOutput.log
done
```

Comment: just google "convert hex to binary using awk" and pick a solution.

Comment: Ed you are extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    for (my $i = 0; $i < length($_); $i += 1) {
        printf('%04b', hex(substr($_, $i, 1)))
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to do it in C

Nevertheless, I had a strange urge to do this with bash' native string replacement....it looks like a form of insanity but it will work....sorry, i just couldn't resist to show you :-)  Are you interested in a C version ?

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE
do
        LINE={LINE//0/zzzz}
        LINE={LINE//1/zzzy}
        LINE={LINE//2/zzyz}
        LINE={LINE//3/zzyy}
        LINE={LINE//4/zyzz}
        LINE={LINE//5/zyzy}
        LINE={LINE//6/zyyz}
        LINE={LINE//7/zyyy}
        LINE={LINE//8/yzzz}
        LINE={LINE//9/yzzy}
        LINE={LINE//a/yzyz}
        LINE={LINE//b/yzyy}
        LINE={LINE//c/yyzz}
        LINE={LINE//d/yyzy}
        LINE={LINE//e/yyyz}
        LINE={LINE//f/yyyy}
        LINE={LINE//y/1}
        LINE={LINE//z/0}
        echo "$LINE"
done < yourhexfile  >yourbinaryfile
```

Comment: this can also be done the same way with sed, maybe faster?